# How to solve $xy=2\int_1^xy(t)dt+5$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

Could you please give me some hint how to solve this equation:
$xy=2\int_1^xy(t)dt+5$.

It is not known whether $y(x)$ is continuous or not, so I could not use Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for differentiating both sides of this equation and thus transform integral equation onto differential one.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that supposing $y \in L^1_{loc}$ implies that $y(x) = \frac{1}{x} (2 \int_1^x y(t) dt +5)$ is continuous. But now, if $y$ is continuous, then it is of class $C^1$.

Comment: Using the method of Laplace transform we obtain $y(x) = 5x$ . Do you agree?

Comment: @Crostul Agreed, but it needs to be stated before differentiating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derivate the equation and use fundamental theorem of calculus to obtain $y(x)+xy'(x)=2y(x)$.
then $xy'(x)-y(x)=0$ devide it by $x^2$ , $\frac{y'(x)}{x^2}-\frac{y(x)}{x}=0$, hence
$(\frac{y(x)}{x})'=0$ then $\frac{y(x)}{x}=c$, so $y(x)= cx$.  substitute in the original equation  you have $cx^2=2\int_{1}^{x}ctdt+5=cx^2-c+5$ and hence $c=5$. then $y(x)=5x$.

Comment: You have to justify that $y$ is differentiable, I think. See Crostul's comment above.

Comment: It follows from theorem fundamental of calculus.

Comment: In the fundamental theorem of calculus, the integrand needs to be continuous.

Comment: sure that $y$ is contiunous out off $0$ since $y=\frac{2\int_{1}^{x}y(t)dt+5}{x}$.  $y$ is at least $L^1$, and hence $\int_{1}^{x} y(t) dt $ is continuous.

Comment: And all of this should be stated beforehand :-)